# Assign renderer to a specific log4net appender

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-appender

I am trying to assign a custom object renderer to an appender as this information is sent to a couple of different locations. I have created the renderer, and that is working correctly, but as I said I don't want all appenders to use the same rendering object.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please share your code and also, well done on the title rhyme.

Comment: The Log4Net documentation is horrible. It seems that `IObjectRenderer`s can only be mapped to types. There is a `RendererMap` that has a `FindAndRender` method that gets an appropriate `IObjectRenderer` for an object based on its type only. My thought was that you could check to see what `Appender` is being used, but that information isn't available to your `IObjectRenderer`.

Comment: [Here on line 656](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Core/LoggingEvent.cs?view=markup) you can see the source code where the `ObjectRenderer`s are used. It's in the LoggingEvent object, which isn't really customizable. What you may want to do instead is create a custom `ILayout`. You could then define your own layout converters, and have them use a different `RendererMap` implementation instead of the one provided in `LoggingEvent`.